# Is there an elegant way to overload a jQuery method inside of a plugin only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a bit of a *dull* moment today, where I can't think of an elegant solution for this problem.

I have inherited a plugin, and I need to modify it to allow passing a *enabled* or *disabled* state to it, to have it detach all of its events, show the *disabled* state, etc.

Like a jQuery UI *plugin*, I was simply going to use...

```
$('div').myPlugin('disabled');
```

This I have no problem with.

However, the plugin attaches many events which are not [namespaced](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). I want the events to be namespaced, so I can remove the events easily.

There are many events that are bound, so I thought *hey, why don't I overload [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach the namespace automatically?*

I came up with this...

```
(function(oldBind) {
    $.fn.bind = function() {
        if (arguments.length >= 2) {
            arguments[0] += '.my-plugin';
        }
        return oldBind.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})($.fn.bind);
```

I placed this at the top of the plugin, before the `return this.each(fn)` code.

It seemed to work nicely.

However, I tossed in a `console.log(arguments[1].toString())` and noticed (as I expected) this overwrote the main jQuery `bind()` outside of the plugin.

What is the best way to have this overloaded `bind()` only available to this plugin?

Should I simply place at end of the plugin `$.fn.bind = oldBind` or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Just save the function before, and then replace it after.

```
var oldBind = $.fn.bind;
$.fn.bind = ...what ever you wanted...
$.fn.bind = oldBind;
```

That should do the trick, it is untested, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: So save a reference to the regular bind, run the plugin code with the altered bind, then set it back, right? I think this is what @alex suggests at the end of the question.

Comment: Yes, there is no easier way. The only other thing I can think of is to replace the code in the old plugin with namespaced bind calls.